# Regular expression for single equal operator

Tags: php, regex, equals

i want to find all `=` operator in C source code. I tried to do this using regular expression and function `pre_match_all()`, but i can't find right one.

Operator that I wanna find: `=`
Operator that I do not wanna find: `+= *= -= /= == &= |= &= ^= <= <<= >= >>= !=`

Comment: You could match every `=` with leading/trailing spaces: `\s=\s`

Comment: @JustinIurman ... if there is a space after or before the `=`. Also the `=` can occur in a string. The final solution has to include a C parser

Comment: @hek2mgl Sure but that's why i said `you could`. It depends on what OP really wants

Answer (score 0):

Try `[^+*-=/_&|\^.....]=` Means any equal except if some has any restricted character before (First `^` means exclusion)

Comment: Check my comment below the question

Comment: @hek2mgl You don't answer the question. There is no reason for guess =  is surrounded by spaces. You are talking about an ideal world.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I'm asking how will your solution handle a situation like this: `char *expression = "1 + 1 = 2";` ?

Comment: In my souce code there are no comment or string where = can be. I have something like this `[^\+\*\-\/=&|%!<>]=[^=]` but it do not work :-/